# Generating new sub timeseries in R

Tags: r

I would like to generate a list of time series based on the column indexs of a master time series (`m`)

```
head(cols)
          [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14] [,15] [,16] [,17] [,18]
    [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
    [2,]    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2     2
    [3,]    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3    4     4     4     4     4     4     4     5     5     5
    [4,]    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11    5     6     7     8     9    10    11     6     7     8
```

so for example the first data.frame in the list would be made from `m[,1], m[,2], m[,3]` and `m[,4]` and look something like

```
              1            2             3            4   
2012-01-01 -0.0248361511  0.0127908458 -0.011976191  0.009987137
2012-01-02 -0.0005351887  0.0290350115  0.004208001  0.007078312
2012-01-03 -0.0016072867  0.0042660695  0.008660648 -0.018255748
2012-01-04  0.0016072867 -0.0001303243  0.001782532 -0.004775416
2012-01-05  0.0026730837 -0.0038740336 -0.007149271  0.015511091
```

And the 14th would be something like

```
              1            2             4            10
2012-01-01 -0.0248361511  0.0127908458  0.009987137  0.0051973431
2012-01-02 -0.0005351887  0.0290350115  0.007078312  0.0081517268
2012-01-03 -0.0016072867  0.0042660695 -0.018255748 -0.0008121889
2012-01-04  0.0016072867 -0.0001303243 -0.004775416  0.0071366761
2012-01-05  0.0026730837 -0.0038740336  0.015511091  0.0186782999
```

is there some function I can write or use in the form

```
apply(cols,2, function(x)  DOSOMETHINGLIKE"a <- merge(a,m[x])"HERE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Some sample data:

   ```
   set.seed(1)
   setRmetricsOptions(myFinCenter = "GMT")
   charvec = timeCalendar()
   TS <- as.timeSeries(matrix(rnorm(60), ncol = 5), charvec)
   head(TS)
   # GMT
   #                  TS.1        TS.2        TS.3       TS.4       TS.5
   # 2012-01-01 -0.6264538 -0.62124058  0.61982575 -0.3942900 -0.1123462
   # 2012-02-01  0.1836433 -2.21469989 -0.05612874 -0.0593134  0.8811077
   # 2012-03-01 -0.8356286  1.12493092 -0.15579551  1.1000254  0.3981059
   # 2012-04-01  1.5952808 -0.04493361 -1.47075238  0.7631757 -0.6120264
   # 2012-05-01  0.3295078 -0.01619026 -0.47815006 -0.1645236  0.3411197
   # 2012-06-01 -0.8204684  0.94383621  0.41794156 -0.2533617 -1.1293631
   ```
2. Verify the `class` of the data to see that it is not a standard `data.frame`:

   ```
   class(TS)
   # [1] "timeSeries"
   # attr(,"package")
   # [1] "timeSeries"
   ```
3. Make a sample matrix from which we will be selecting the columns from the TS object created above:

   ```
   GetMe <- replicate(3, sample(5, 3))
   GetMe
   #      [,1] [,2] [,3]
   # [1,]    5    1    3
   # [2,]    2    4    1
   # [3,]    4    2    4
   ```
4. Use `lapply` to subset according to the column-wise values from the above matrix:

   ```
   myList <- lapply(1:ncol(GetMe), function(x) TS[, GetMe[, x]])
   myList[[1]] # View one of the resulting subsetted data
   # GMT
   #                  TS.5        TS.2       TS.4
   # 2012-01-01 -0.1123462 -0.62124058 -0.3942900
   # 2012-02-01  0.8811077 -2.21469989 -0.0593134
   # 2012-03-01  0.3981059  1.12493092  1.1000254
   # 2012-04-01 -0.6120264 -0.04493361  0.7631757
   # 2012-05-01  0.3411197 -0.01619026 -0.1645236
   # 2012-06-01 -1.1293631  0.94383621 -0.2533617
   # 2012-07-01  1.4330237  0.82122120  0.6969634
   # 2012-08-01  1.9803999  0.59390132  0.5566632
   # 2012-09-01 -0.3672215  0.91897737 -0.6887557
   # 2012-10-01 -1.0441346  0.78213630 -0.7074952
   # 2012-11-01  0.5697196  0.07456498  0.3645820
   # 2012-12-01 -0.1350546 -1.98935170  0.7685329
   ```
5. Verify the `class`es of the objects in this list:

   ```
   lapply(myList, class)
   # [[1]]
   # [1] "timeSeries"
   # attr(,"package")
   # [1] "timeSeries"
   # 
   # [[2]]
   # [1] "timeSeries"
   # attr(,"package")
   # [1] "timeSeries"
   # 
   # [[3]]
   # [1] "timeSeries"
   # attr(,"package")
   # [1] "timeSeries"
   ```
6. **In the future** *please provide a reproducible example and be specific in your question about what you are actually working with (for example, which packages you have used to create your data, what is currently loaded, and so on). Your question clearly states you are working with `data.frame`s, but your comment to my original answer reveals you're actually working with a `timeSeries` object from the `timeSeries` package which requires a (slightly) different approach.*

Comment: This works as a data.frame but I was hoping to avoid the conversation back and forth between a timeseries and data.frame

Comment: @lab_notes, What do you mean by "a timeseries"? What is the structure of your equivalent of "myDF" in this example? If you post a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) you are more likely to get more useful answers.

Comment: as in timeseries from http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/timeSeries/timeSeries.pdf

Comment: @lab_notes, that comment should really be a part of your original question since there are different packages that deal with time series data in R, including functions in base R. It is always good to specify in your questions what packages are being used; if you can also share a sample dataset, that would be very helpful.

Comment: Thanks very much, In future I will provide reproducible examples.